# Не работает мульти бэкграунд

Tags: css

отображается только первый бэкграунд.

```
body
{
background:url(images/demo_bg.gif), url(images/demo_background.jpg);
background-position: center bottom, left top;
       width: 100%;
       position:relative;
       height:100%;
}
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8fr/)

Answer (score 1):

На jsfiddle один ваш фон перекрывает другой.

Попробуйте [так](http://jsfiddle.net/vr8fr/1/):

```
background:url(images/demo_bg.gif) repeat-y, url(images/demo_background.jpg) repeat-x;
```

Comment: как можно задать область распространения repeat-a?

Comment: Насколько я знаю у background-repeat нет возможности задать область распространения, кроме space и round и xy направления:

http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-repeat

Но возможно вам поможет http://htmlbook.ru/css/background-position

И общий синтаксис свойства background чтобы не запутаться
http://htmlbook.ru/css/background